# "type" and "which" programs coming up empty for programs on the path

Tags: bash

Here is an example of a program that is in the path, find-able by tab / command-completion and accessible but not found by `which`:

kafka-

[image]

However running `which kafka` or `type kafka` comes up empty handed

[image]

Why would these programs not be working properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in your first screenshot, there is no application called and ‘kafka-‘.  Therefore, it cannot look up its path.

Try, for example, ‘which kafka-configs’ and it will show you the path.

Comment: Oh so it's simply that _auto_completion does not work..  I seem to recall  auto-completion working .. maybe just in linux? I am trying now on my AWS instance ..

Comment: ah i guess autocompletion simply does not work for them. Not sure where/why I had the impression it did..

Comment: autocompletion does not know what to do because there are too many choices. I guess you produced the first screenshot by double tapping? Only recently i noticed that there can be different behaviours for autocompletion. Some (maybe newer versions?) cycle through the commands, which is maybe what you are expecting to see, and some wait until you give them another clue, i.e. letter. But this is may be another question ;)

Comment: It's not the case that there are too many choices - given that auto-completion for just executing the command works fine.  It appears that these commands really do not have auto-completion and I'm "remembering" a behavior that did not exist.